# IntelliJ with spring-boot-jetty-jsp

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot, jetty

I'm trying to run the spring-boot-jetty-jsp sample. It works from the command line using `mvn jetty:run` but when I try it in IntelliJ I get this error:

```
2016-07-16 02:54:25.150  INFO 19012 --- [           main] s.jetty.jsp.SampleJettyJspApplication    : Starting SampleJettyJspApplication on dac-Latitude-E7450 with PID 19012 (/home/dac/proj/spring-boot-master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp/target/classes started by dac in /home/dac/proj/spring-boot-master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp)
2016-07-16 02:54:25.153  INFO 19012 --- [           main] s.jetty.jsp.SampleJettyJspApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-07-16 02:54:25.252  INFO 19012 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3ad83a66: startup date [Sat Jul 16 02:54:25 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-16 02:54:25.402  WARN 19012 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [sample.jetty.jsp.SampleJettyJspApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
2016-07-16 02:54:25.426 ERROR 19012 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [sample.jetty.jsp.SampleJettyJspApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:187) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sample.jetty.jsp.SampleJettyJspApplication.main(SampleJettyJspApplication.java:33) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:301) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:204) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.BUILD-20160715.204924-12.jar:4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:36461', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It is possible to create a maven configuration in IntelliJ and run the `jetty:run` argument with that configuration, then it works. But what does the above error mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the example lists Jetty starter dependency as `provided` so IntelliJ does not include it in your module, making `ServletContext` class unavailable, thus causing the `NoClassDefFound` exception.

Change the definition of spring-boot-starter-jetty dependency in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
    <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
</dependency>
```

and refresh/reimport the maven project in IntelliJ.

Alternatively, if you do not wish to change the example code, you can manually edit the dependencies in your module's settings in IntelliJ - simply change all Provided dependencies to Compile and it should yield a similar result.

Comment: But when I change it, I can't use the root `/` request mapping which is for my jsp. Why not? I'm just trying to use some jsp. I had to also comment out the `provided` from the org.eclipse.jetty, then my root request mapping works and my jsp renders.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, apache-jsp should also have been a compile dependency, I'll update the answer so that others also see it. The trouble with the example is the fact that it uses packaging of type `war`, meaning that it's supposed to be deployable to a server. If those dependencies weren't set to `provided` you wouldn't be able to properly deploy it.